# jquery plugin - autocomplete results in separate field?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

Any known jquery plugin for doing this? Basically, bootstrap typeahead but with the results displayed in separate multi-select field.

I'm not a web developer, just a guy trying to get something done. I'm willing to put in the hours learning js and jquery if I must, but I'd rather use a plugin. ;) anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inspired me to create a quick and dirty plugin using Twitter Bootstrap typeahead as the foundation.  I didn't bother to check if others were out there, because I wanted a simple version for myself anyway.  It's definitely not overly robust, but I think it gets the job done.  Let me know what you think and if I should spend some more time with it :)

Super Simple DropAhead.

https://github.com/Mattbo1130/DropAhead

Comment: That's exactly it! I loaded your index.html and it worked just as called for. If I was to attempt the same it would have required a couple weeks ramp-up followed by some really shoddy code. Starred on github!

Comment: Glad you like it. I'll have to spend some more time customizing and upgrading :)